# Root pointer shifts to point at the word being inserted in the binary search tree

Tags: c, pointers, file-io, insert, binary-search-tree

so i wrote a program to read words from a file and insert, remove or search them in a binary search tree. It seemed like everything was working fine but somehow when inserting a word in a binary search tree, from the second word onwards the root pointer I pass as the parameter of the insert function is shifted to point at the word being inserted. So instead of inserting the word the function only increases the occurence of the first word. I sincerely don't know how this is happening. Does anyone know what could be the problem?

my structs:

```
    typedef char * TypeKey;
    typedef struct TypeItem {
    TypeKey Key; //[MAXTAM];
    int counting;
    } TypeItem;

    typedef struct Node * Pointer

    typedef struct Node {
    TypeItem Reg;
    Pointer Left, Right;
    } node;

   typedef Pointer TypeTree;
```

The insert function:

```
   void Insert (TypeItem * x, Pointer * p){


if (*p == NULL){
*p= (Pointer)malloc(sizeof(Node));
 (*p)->Reg = *x;
 (*p)->Left = NULL;
 (*p)->Right = NULL;
 printf("insert %s\n",x->Key);
 return;
    }

if (strcmp(x->Key,(*p)->Reg.Key)< 0){
    Insert(x, &(*p)->Left);

   }
if (strcmp(x->Key,(*p)->Reg.Key) > 0)
    Insert(x, &(*p)->Right);

else {
    (*p)->Reg.counting ++;
    printf("increases %s\n",x->Key);
    return;
    }
   }
```

And i just declare the root pointer "arvore" on main like this:

```
    Pointer arvore = NULL;

    TypeItem item;
    item.Key = Palavra;
    item.counting = 1;

  Insert(&item, arvore);
```

If anyone could help me understand what is the wrong it would be really nice.

Comment: At a minimum, I think you should translate your names into English.

Comment: Hey, why do you change the whole code? Also this truely is unreadable. I surely won't reformat it again.

Answer (score 0):

You have undefined behavior in your code

First you declare `arvore` of type `Apontador`, and then assign `NULL` to that pointer. Then you call `Insere` with `arvore` as argument, but `Insere` want a *pointer* to an `Apontador`, meaning you have one level of indirection to little in the call. This shouldn't even compile, or at least give a warning (warnings are a very good sign that you're doing something you shouldn't be doing).

And when inside the `Insere` function, you dereference the pointer `p` (which is `arvore` in the call) which is `NULL`, leading to undefined behavior.

You should call the function using the address-of operator `&` for the second argument as well:

```
Insere(&item, &arvore);
```

---

Also, if `Palavra` is a pointer to e.g. an array defined locally in a function, that pointer will no longer be valid once that function returns. If it's so then you have another case of undefined behavior.

Comment: I don't think it needs to be valid once the function returns, I was using it to take the words and place them into the tree. I fixed the argument as you sugested, and all the words are being inserted into the tree. But now if it's not increasing the occurence of repeated words. It seems arvore is always NULL, even after you create the first node. Do you kow what could it be? Thanks for the help.

Comment: @foxglove Yes it needs to be valid, because you don't actually don't copy the value, just the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

[Too long for a comment]

I did not dive to the ground but this line

```
(*p)->Reg = *x;
```

copies a `TypeItem` and with it copies one of its members, namely `TypeKey Key` with `Key` being a pointer `char *`. I strongly assume here a deep copy is needed, you need to duplicate what the pointer `Key` points to.

It is not fully clear as we do not see who you fully initialies your node.